# Why socket io is showing not found error?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, chat

I am trying to learn socket.io for private chat in my project
In my backend i am using node and express and sending chat page on route "/chat"

**app.js**

```
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { router } from "./routes/web.js";
import { connectDb } from "./db/connectDb.js";
// configuring dotenv
dotenv.config();

// initialize app
const app = express();
// server
const node__server = http.createServer(app);

// static files
app.use(express.static('../frontend'));

// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// load routes
app.use("/", router);

// define template engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// connecting database
connectDb(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

// Listening to browser port
node__server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening at http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

export { node__server };
```

**chatHandle.js**

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { node__server } from "./app";
// socket 
const io = new Server(node__server);

io.of("/chat").on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
})
```

**in client.js (script of chat page)**

```
const socket = io("/chat");
socket.on("connect",()=>{
    console.log("client connected");
})
```

[image]

Comment: Because you never started your socket io server. You called listen on `node_server` but then you created a new server that you didn't call `listen` on

Comment: my server is running on 8400

Comment: @Konrad - The current code shows an http server that is started and that server is used for socket.io.  So, that part of things should be OK.

Comment: i did same thing with project only cotaining one view file then it worked but not working this time

Comment: How are you starting this app?  If you're doing `node app.js`, then the problem is that nothing is every loading chatHandle.js.  It would probably work if you did `node chatHandle.js` to start it because that file wiill load `app.js` for you.  You can't load `chatHandle.js` from within `app.js` because that will create a circular dependency where `app.js` loads `chatHandle.js` and `chatHandle.js` loads `app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting your original code with this:

```
node app.js
```

Then, a problem is that the `chatHandle.js` code is never loaded or run.  So, you never get a Socket.io server attached to your http server.

It appears you could fix that by just changing your startup to:

```
node chatHandle.js
```

because `chatHandle.js` loads `app.js`.  The way your code is currently organized, you can't just load `chatHandle.js` from `app.js` because that would create a circular dependency where `chatHandle.js` loads `app.js` and `app.js` loads `chatHandle.js`.

My preferred structure would to be load `chatHandle.js` from `app.js`, but have `chatHandle.js` not do any initialization on load.  Instead, export a `socketioInit()` function and then call that from `app.js` and pass it the `server` instance so it can then set up socket.io using that server.  This makes your socket.io completely independent from the creation of the server and it could be used in a different project that sets up the http server differently.

Answer (score 0):

**app.js**

```
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { router } from "./routes/web.js";
import { connectDb } from "./db/connectDb.js";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { chatManage } from "./chathandle.js";
// configuring dotenv
dotenv.config();

// initialize app
const app = express();
// server
const node__server = http.createServer(app);

// static files
app.use(express.static('../frontend'));

// middlewares
// extented true allows to have nested valuse and false prvents this                         
nested valuess
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// load routes
app.use("/", router);

// define template engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// connecting database
connectDb(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

// socket
const io = new Server(node__server);
// listen chat request
io.of("/chat").on("connection", (socket) => {
    chatManage(socket);
});

// Listening to browser port
node__server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening at             
    http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

**chathandle.js**

```
function chatManage(socket) {
    console.log("From server socket id is ", socket.id);

        socket.on("message", (msg) => {
            // socket.broadcast.emit(eventName,dataObject)
            socket.broadcast.emit("message", msg);
        })
        socket.on("success", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg.message, msg.id);
        })
        socket.on("failed", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg.message, msg.id);
        })
}

export { chatManage };
```

**client.js**

```
const socket = io("/chat");
socket.on("connect",()=>{
    console.log("client connected");
})
```